# Typecasting in Java Nashorn (Javascript which Support Java)

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, nodelist, typecasting-operator

I want to achieve this NodeList typecasting in java Nashorn - `NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)`
But I am not able to do such typecasting in Nashorn even for other examples. Like it always give me error when I do `(some type) object` . When I do as below

```
NodeList = Java.type("org.w3c.dom.NodeList") 
objItem = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(xmldoc, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODESET)
```

where expr is XPath expression and xmldoc is Document doc of Java.

then I get error saying - expected ; but found expr

When I do `objItem = new NodeList(expr.evaluate(xmldoc, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODESET))`

then I get error as com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dtmnodelist@1ffcd2aa is not an object.
Please let me know how can I do typecasting in Java Nashorn for the same or similar example. I am not able to find any resources for that other than https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html.

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast? JavaScript doesn't have the concept of casting.

Comment: @ThomasKläger, after getting NodeList I want to iterate over its item and apply methods like getAttribute("attributeName") of Node interface of Java. So, I thought I need to typecast it to NodeList. Currently I am working on xpath validation. Seems there is some problem with XML namespace in my code. I just wanted to know if it is possible to do typecasting like this in Java Nashorn.

Comment: In JavaScript you don't need to cast. If you pass `XPathConstants.NODESET` to `expr.evaluate()` then you'll get a `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` instance and you can just call the methods declared by `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` like `objItem.getLength()` or `objItem.item(0)`